# Finding out if a linked list is even or odd length

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I want to find out if linked list is of odd or even length.

I have a pointer which moves at two times the speed. If the length of linked list is even,the fast pointer will eventually reach null. If the length of linked list is odd the fast pointer will reach the end;

```
    //Method 1  Works

    int isLengthEvenOrOdd(struct Node* head){
         Node *fast;
         fast=head;

         if(head==NULL)
            return 0;

         while(fast && fast->next!=NULL){
             fast=fast->next->next;
         }

         if(fast==NULL)
            return 0;
         else
            return 1;
    }


    //Method 2  Segmentation Fault

    int isLengthEvenOrOdd(struct Node* head){
         Node *fast;
         fast=head;

         if(head==NULL)
            return 0;

         while(head && fast->next!=NULL){
             fast=fast->next->next;
         }

         if(fast==NULL)
            return 0;
         else
            return 1;
    }
```

Could anybody tell me why the below code is wrong?

```
while(head && fast->next!=NULL){
         fast=fast->next->next;
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger, looking at the value of `fast` each time it's dereferenced?

Comment: Well because it doesn't check that `fast` is NULL, unlike the working version.

Comment: Unlreated but why are you returning an integer from what should be a boolean function?

Comment: And don't you already have to implement a `Length` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at these two instructions (I am assuming that there is nothing in between)

```
     if(head==NULL)
        return 0;

     while(head && fast->next!=NULL){
         fast=fast->next->next;
     }
```

`head` will never be NULL in the `while()` condition, so you are always checking only `fast->next`. Once you get to the end, `fast` is NULL and you get your segmentation fault.

Suggestion, don't take it the wrong way, get yourself a nice IDE (there are many free) and learn how to use a debugger. If you want to go more hardcore, continue using a text editor and used gdb or whatever debugger you prefer. Your productivity will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this part of the code:

```
while(head && fast->next!=NULL){
    fast=fast->next->next;
}
```

the head will never be null

now say the list is 
                    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
                    head
                    fast
after 1st iteration
    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
    head
              fast

now see according to the code
    fast-> next is not null so it goes inside the loop

```
and sets fast to "fast->next-> next"
which makes
fast = null as

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null 
head
                    fast
```

So when you try to access "next" of null you run into a segmentation fault

Code1 works because of the condition fast && fast-> next

since you are checking the existence of fast first you never tried to access something that didn't exist. The code exited the loop on fast = null only which didn't happen in Code2